# Form validation with WTForms and and autofill SQLAlchemy model with form data in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a form that i have to validate and then save the data in the database. I have a `SQLAlchemy` model called `Campaign` which looks something like this

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
class Campaign(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'campaigns'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    priority = db.Column(db.SmallInteger)
    starts_at = db.Column(db.Date)
    ends_at = db.Column(db.Date)
    .... bla bla bla
```

Now i have a `WTForm` form for validation like this

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form, TextField, IntegerField, DateField, Required, NumberRange
class CampaignForm(Form):

    def date_validation(form, field):
        #some validation on date

    name = TextField(validators=[Required()])
    priority = IntegerField(validators=[Required(), NumberRange(min=1,max=100)])
    start_date = DateField(validators=[Required(), date_validation])
    end_date = DateField(validators=[Required(), date_validation])
    ... bla bla bla
```

Now to validate and save the form data, I can do something like this is my `view`

`code in Flask`

```
class CampaignsView(MethodView):
    def post(self):
        """
        For creating a new campaign
        """
        form = CampaignForm(request.form)
        if form.validate():
            campaign = Campaign(form.name.data, form.priority.data, and so on )
            session.add(campaign)
```

Now the above code is stupid because i have to hard-code every field name in the view. Is there some other way where i can fill the fields of my model with form fields?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the .populate_obj method like this:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    campaign = Campaign()
    form.populate_obj(campaign)
```

Also check out the [docs](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj) on this.

Comment: That's great. And is there any way to avoid generating the same logical class once for the form, and once for the database? Can one generate one class for both?

Comment: @famargar not sure whether I understand your question?

Answer (score 4):

there is wtforms extension for sqlalachemy:

- WTForms Documentation ->
  http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy

also somethings can help you

- kvesteri/wtforms-alchemy · GitHub ->
  https://github.com/kvesteri/wtforms-alchemy
- Automatically create a WTForms Form from model | Flask (A Python
  Microframework) ->    http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/60/

from links:

```
from flaskext.wtf import Form
from wtforms.ext.appengine.db import model_form
from models import MyModel

MyForm = model_form(MyModel, Form)
```

Comment: In (this)[http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/60/] approach i have to pass validators in the `field_args` argument of `model_form`. Cant i use my form class `CampaignForm`?

Comment: @lovesh no, you can extend data with field_args.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate() == True:
    create new user
```

and send the user to a desired page